# GraphQL "all" in array query?

Tags: graphql, strapi

I'm trying to build a GraphQL query within Strapi (probably not relevant) and I'm not sure how to achieve what I want. So far I've got the following, which is close, but `name_in` isn't quite what I want.

```
query {
  events(where: { audiences: { name_in: ["Year 1", "Biology"] } }) {
    name
    audiences {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is events where all of the audience names overlap with the provided query which I ultimately wish to parameterise. Here `_in` is obviously doing an `any`.  So I only want records with `["Year 1"]`, `["Biology"]` or `["Year 1", "Biology"]`. Anything else such as `["Year 2", "Biology"]` should not be returned as the complete set of audiences doesn't completely overlap.

Is this possible with vanilla GraphQL or do I need to start write custom resolvers?

Comment: 'vanilla GraphQL' deosn't define any filtering/searching syntax or behaviour - check strapi docs, this case should be covered